# Programmatically compare row data from 2 CSV files

Tags: c#, csv, comparison

I have 2 CSV files with 7 columns each.
CSV file 1 stores current or old data.
CSV file 2 stores the new data to be updated into CSV file 1.

I'd like to programmatically compare each row entry per column of the CSV files, & if a change is detected, generate a SQL script that can be run to auto update this data into CSV file 1.

E.g. if CSV file 1 has a string value called "three" stored under column "number" with ID value 1, & CSV file 2 has a string value called "zwei" stored under the same column with the same ID value, then CSV file 1's value of "three" should be changed to "zwei", but this has to be done via a programmatically generated SQL script.

Please assist...

Comment: What did you try? Where did you fail?

Comment: are you looking for help with how to write SQL statements? How to create a SQL data provider for C# and connect it to a file? How to compare two tables of data? Or are you trying to ask all the above? (hint: the last option is a bad idea, your question will be closed for being too broad)

Answer (score 3):

I would load both files into SQL Temp tables, process line by line and do updates in SQL. Then overwrite CSV file 1 completely.

This is fast and easy.